# yahoo's attribute exchange -> blank data is coming

Tags: php, openid, yahoo-oauth, attribute-exchange

I am trying to build openid login system for my website. To do this I used [JanRain's php openid library](http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.3/) v 2.1.3.

I am also using [openid selector](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) to select the openid provider from the list.

I first created the attributes array that I need to fetch from the provider as follows:

```
$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/contact/email',2,1, 'email');
$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',1,1, 'firstname');
$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/namePerson/last',1,1, 'lastname');
$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/namePerson',1,1, 'fullname');
$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly',1,1, 'username');

$ax = new Auth_OpenID_AX_FetchRequest;

foreach($attribute as $attr)
{
    $ax->add($attr);
}
$auth_request->addExtension($ax);
```

and in the finish_auth.php file I wrote this to fetch the attributes returned

```
$ax = new Auth_OpenID_AX_FetchResponse();
$obj = $ax->fromSuccessResponse($response);
```

Google gives me all the attributes requested but yahoo doesn't (as stated **[here](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2009/12/yahoo_openid_now_with_attribute_exchange.html)** that yahoo now supports attribute exchange).

Is there any limitation set by yahoo on attribute exchange too. (they give limited websites access to sreg extension of openid). :(

Please help me, I am stuck over here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem for Yahoo is solved !!! 
check out here: [php-openID doesn't work with Yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616123/php-openid-doesnt-work-with-yahoo/2620558#2620558)