# php-openID doesn't work with Yahoo

Tags: php, openid, janrain, yahoo-oauth

i am trying to use php-openid library for implementing openID in my site.
the basic consumer example inside its package doesn't work for Google and Yahoo.
i found the Google solution here:
[Example usage of AX in PHP OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183788/example-usage-of-ax-in-php-openid/2612816)
but it doesn't still work for Yahoo! .
how can i made it works?

Comment: no answer?? help is really needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**wow it is solved now !!!!!**

i traced the functions and found the problem.and that is....
in "try_auth.php" file i used

```
"$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/contact/email',2,1, 'email');"
```

for getting the user email from provider. it works fine in Google because Google ignore '2' (count of requested email address) but in Yahoo! it generate [count.email] => 2 for it (in getSignedNS function) and in Yahoo response there is no entry for count.email. it causes to return null in getSignedNS for Yahoo.
i changed

```
"$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/contact/email',2,1, 'email');"
```

to

```
"$attribute[] = Auth_OpenID_AX_AttrInfo::make('http://axschema.org/contact/email',1,1, 'email');"
```

and it works fine now and return whatever i requested from both provider !!!

lol...